# can i call task from from always block in verilog

Tags: task, verilog

I am getting an error - "tests is not a function name." What am I doing wrong here? Can I not call a task from always block?

```
task automatic tests(
    input a, 
    input b, 
    output  c); 
    // code
endtask

module test123
(
input   clk,
input   a,
input   b,
input   e
); 

reg d; 

always @(posedge clk) 
    if(e)
        d <= tests(a, b);       

endmodule
```

Comment: Since `c` is output from task, you need to do: `if(e) tests(a,b,d);`. This will give output in `reg d`.

Comment: Either use function, which can return the value, or pass LHS operand as an argument to task.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it as shown below,

```
module test123
(
input   clk,
input   a,
input   b,
input   e
); 

task automatic tests(
    input a, 
    input b, 
    output  c); 
    // code
endtask

reg d; 

always @(posedge clk) 
    if(e)
                            // a=a, b=b, d=c
      tests(a, b, d);       // d is assigned to your output

endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

Tasks never return values - only a function can do that. Also, unless you are using SystemVerilog, tasks and functions must be declared inside a module.